# Objective-C performSelector when to use colon?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Do you only postfix the method name with a : if you are calling a foreign object?

For some reason

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myMethod:) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
```

Does not work but

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
```

Does!

EDIT:

Declared in the implementation of a class but not the interface.

```
- (void)myMethod
{
   // Some stuff
}
```

Comment: How id myMethod declared - ie what is the method signature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The colon represents a method argument. Since **myMethod** takes no arguments its selector can't have a colon. If you had multiple arguments like this...

```
- (void)myMethod:(id)method object:(id)object enabled:(BOOL)bool {
  // Some Stuff
}
```

... the selector would be **@selector(myMethod:object:enabled:)**

Answer (score 4):

In Objective-C the colons are part of the method name. That is, `myMethod` and `myMethod:` are distinct selectors (and in your case, only the latter exists).

For instance, for a method declared like:

```
-(void)doSomethingWithFoo:(int)foo andBar:(int)bar;
```

The selector is `doSomethingWithFoo:andBar:`.

Comment: actually, in his case, only the former exists.