# Use colon : or not with selectors

Tags: objective-c, selector

I was wondering: what's the difference between writing a selector name with no colon `@selector(mySelector)`, or `@selector(mySelector:)` with the colon?

As in:

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWith... 
                                                       target:self
                                                       action:@selector(addAction:)];
```

I can't find another example without the colon, but I'm quite sure I have already seen some of them.

Comment: Colon means there is a parameter, without colon means there is no parameter after this piece.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C performSelector -- when to use colon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546372/objective-c-performselector-when-to-use-colon); also [When to use a colon with a selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953623/when-to-use-a-colon-with-a-selector)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The colon is needed after the method's name **if and only if** the method takes an argument.

No function parameters:

```
-(void)addAction {}

// Use ...@selector(addAction)...
```

Has parameter:

```
-(void)addAction:(id)info {}

// Use ...@selector(addAction:)...
```

Answer (score 1):

In certain cases, the number of colons can determine arguments. For example, if you pass in an action method with one colon, it'll send the `sender` as the first argument. If you pass in a selector with two colons, you'll get the `event` as well. No colon means, obviously, no arguments.

Comment: In which cases the number of colons doesn’t determine the number of arguments?

Comment: I know it does in the case of target-action, but I'm thinking that the plain 'performSelector' method (not the ones that take arguments) might have an issue with that—at best it'd pass in nil arguments.