# Creating dynamic UITextFields and adding UIControlEvents.EditingChanged events: who called me?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, ios8

I am creating two TextFields dynamically and adding them the EditingChanged event like in the following example

```
import UIKit

var view:UIView = UIView()

let inp1:UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: 100, height: 44))

inp1.addTarget(view, action:  "text_updated", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)

let inp2:UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 50, width: 100, height: 44))

inp2.addTarget(view, action:  "text_updated", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)


view.addSubview(inp1)
view.addSubview(inp2)

func text_updated(){
    println("who has called me?")
}
```

As it is there is no way to know which one of the controls has called the text_updated function.

When I pass the TextField as a parameter

```
func text_updated(sender: UITextField) {

}
```

I get an "unrecognized selector sent to instance" exception.

How is it possible to know which TextField was changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between `text_updated` and `text_updated:` is subtle and it's quite easy to forget the colon.

If you want to call `func text_updated(sender: UITextField)` (method with at least one parameter), you have to set your textField target selector to `"text_updated:"`, just like this:

```
inp2.addTarget(view, action:  "text_updated:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
```

In fact, when you're dealing with selectors, the rule is simple (from [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7310415/1966109)):

> The colon is needed after the method's name if and only if the method
>   takes an argument.